# Android: Clicking own AdMob ads?

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

I understand that during development, you are supposed to use the test devices (either xml tags or java code behind) to show test ads on your own devices to avoid clicking your own ads before releasing an app for production in the PlayStore.

My question is that once an app is in production, in the PlayStore, is it not fair game for the developer to click ads? After turning off test ads for upload to PlayStore does AdMob know that it is the developer that is clicking ads? How?

Comment: You don't have to turn off test ads for your device for the Play Store.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal matters, not programming.

Comment: fine i'll go elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Google's stance seems pretty unambiguous to me. [AdMob publisher guidelines and policies](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en)

> Publishers may not click their own ads or use any means to inflate
>   impressions and/or clicks artificially, including manual methods.
>   Testing your own ads by clicking on them is not allowed.